# Приоритетная сортировка ORACLE DB

Tags: sql, база-данных, oracle

УСЛОВИЯ : Сделать номера отделов в указанном порядке 10, 30, 20

Из-за некоторых условий использую union. Но проблема в том что он выводит не по заданном порядке, а по своей сортировке. Которую можно сделать ASC,DESC. Но надо именно вывод указанный в условии.

```
select deptno, job
from emp 
where deptno=10 
union
(select deptno, job 
 from emp 
 where deptno=30 
  union 
select deptno,job 
from emp 
where deptno=20);
```

Answer (score 3):

Вот так попробуйте:

```
select deptno, job, 1 as ord
from emp 
where deptno=10 
union
(select deptno, job, 2 as ord
 from emp 
 where deptno=30 
  union 
select deptno,job, 3 as ord
from emp 
where deptno=20)
Order by ord ASK;
```

Comment: Спасибо, решил по-другому. Сделал через union all, и добавил к выборкам deptno  DISTINCT

Comment: Спасибо и вам за то что дали ответ!

Comment: @IlyaBurmaka Через union all вы решили не правильно. SQL _не гарантирует_ порядка строк ни в каком случае, кроме указания предложения order by. Если вы без order by получили правильный порядок строк, то это не означает, что завтра, когда оптимизатор решит по другому посмотреть на запрос, этот порядок не изменится. Так что вариант, предложенный в данном ответе, единственно возможный, действительно гарантирующий работу при любых обстоятельствах